# Медленно работает WPF контрол (самодельный HighlightTextBlock с выделением подстроки)

Tags: c#, wpf, производительность, controls, .net-4.0

Подскажите, почему у меня тормозит контрол, при том, что вызывается из параллельного потока.

Пытаюсь для **.NET 4.0** сделать контрол (*HighlightTextBlock*), который бы выделял желтым подтекст. Идея в том, что если подтекст найден, то у *ContentControl*-а *Content* становится *TextBlock*-ом из 3-ех *Run*-ов, один из которых выделен желтым цветом.

- `result.Add(new Run(stringBefore));`
- `result.Add(new Run(stringMatch) { Background = this.HighlightBrush });`
- `result.Add(new Run(stringAfter));`

Если подтекст не найден, то вставляется просто текст.

Уже все получилось и работает, но проблема с производительностью.

Опишу подробнее:

Данный контрол используется в листе, где может быть несколько сотен записей. Подтекст редактируется в *TextBox*-е. Биндинг к этому текст-боксу происходит так: `HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"`. Если редактировать данный подтекст, то зависает, курсор "прыгает", как на картинке. На каждое нажатие клавиши выполняется код для выделения текста и очень заметно, что притормаживает уже при 30 строках с моим контролом.

При стирании текста должно плавно стираться, но на самом деле не плавно:
[image: то как ведет себя текст бокс]

Внутри своего контрола пробовал и так делать:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
(ThreadStart)delegate
{
    //update control
}
);
```

И так, через асинхронность:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(/*поиск в строке и разбиение строки на 3 части*/)
    .ContinueWith(
        x =>
        {
            //update control
        }
        ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
        );
```

Но от тормозов избавиться не получилось.

Проверить контрол можно на простом примере (пишу сходу, от руки). Затормаживание происходит уже при 30 строках.

```
<TextBox Name="myTextBox"/>
<ItemsControl>
    <ItemsControl.Items>
        <!-- ... -->
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <controls:HighlightTextBlock Text = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" HighlightText = "{Binding ElementName=myTextBox, Path=Text}"/>
        <!-- ... -->
    </ItemsControl.Items>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

Вот обещанный полный код контрола. Тормозит и с дебагером и без.

```
public class HighlightTextBlock : ContentControl
{

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(TextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(TextProperty_PropertyChanged)));

    private static void TextProperty_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as HighlightTextBlock;
        control.SetContent();
    }



    public string HighlightText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HighlightTextProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(HighlightTextProperty, value);
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightText", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock), new UIPropertyMetadata("", new PropertyChangedCallback(HighlightTextProperty_PropertyChanged)));

    private static void HighlightTextProperty_PropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as HighlightTextBlock;
        control.SetContent();
    }

    public Brush HighlightBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("HighlightBrush",
        typeof(Brush),
        typeof(HighlightTextBlock),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange));


    static HighlightTextBlock()
    {
        //DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ContentControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ContentControl)));
    }


    private TextBlock TextContent
    {
        get { return Content as TextBlock; }
        set { Content = value as TextBlock; }
    }


    public HighlightTextBlock()
    {
        TextContent = new TextBlock();
        SetContent();
    }

    private void SetContent()
    {

        //TextContent.Text = Text;

        var tmpText = Text;
        var tmpHighlightText = HighlightText;
        /*Task.Factory.StartNew<CombinedText>(() => GetCombined(txt, hghlghtTxt))
            .ContinueWith(
                x =>
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("------- XXXXXXXX -------");
                    var text = (CombinedText)x.Result;

                    TextContent = new TextBlock();
                    TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Before ?? ""));
                    TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Match ?? "") { Background = HighlightBrush });
                    TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.After ?? ""));

                    Debug.WriteLine("---------ZZZZZZZZ------------");
                }
                ,TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()
            );*/

        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
            (ThreadStart)delegate
            {
                var text = GetCombined(tmpText, tmpHighlightText);
                TextContent = new TextBlock();
                TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Before ?? ""));
                TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Match ?? "") { Background = HighlightBrush });
                TextContent.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.After ?? ""));
            }
            );
    }

    private CombinedText GetCombined(string text, string highlightText)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("------------1111---------------");
        var result = new CombinedText();
        SharpDebug.WriteLine(text);
        SharpDebug.WriteLine(highlightText);

        if (text != null && highlightText != null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("-----------2222----------------");
            var queryLength = highlightText.Length;
            var sourceLength = text.Length;

            var index = text.IndexOf(highlightText, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);

            if (index >= 0)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("-------------3333--------------");
                var stringBefore = text.Substring(0, index);
                var stringMatch = text.Substring(index, queryLength);
                var stringAfter = text.Substring(index + queryLength, sourceLength - (index + queryLength));

                if (stringBefore.Length > 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-------------4444--------------");
                    result.Before = stringBefore;
                }

                if (stringMatch.Length > 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("------------5555---------------");
                    result.Match = stringMatch;
                }

                if (stringAfter.Length > 0)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("-------------6666--------------");
                    result.After = stringAfter;
                }

                Debug.WriteLine("------------7777---------------");
                return result;
            }
        }
        Debug.WriteLine("-------------9999--------------");

        result.Before = text;
        return result;
    }
}

internal struct CombinedText
{
    public string Before { get; set; }
    public string Match { get; set; }
    public string After { get; set; }
} 

internal static class ControlExtensions
{
    public static void Clear(this TextBlock text)
    {
        text.Text = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: А у вас не происходит случайно рекурсивный вызов самого себя? Если вам не сложно, приведите, пожалуйста, полный компилируемый пример.

Comment: Хорошо, подожду. Присылайте, ваша задача выглядит интересно.

Comment: Покамест написал вот такое: http://pastebin.com/7Xw0BsrN, но оно всё равно подтормаживает. Подумаю ещё.

Comment: Возможно, если не выносить разбиение строки в новый поток. будет быстрее, т. к. оно должно быть достаточно быстрым. Переписал `SetContent()`, оставил только паузу. http://pastebin.com/Qyqb2UZx

Comment: @VladD, благодарю! Вы бы могли вынести это решение из ссылки в отдельный ответ, чтобы более заметно было на случай если кому-то еще понадобится.

Comment: Готово, написал.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я попробовал немного ускорить выполнение. Получается скорее, чем исходный вариант, хотя всё ещё не совершенно.

```
public class HighlightTextBlock : ContentControl
{
    #region dependency property string Text, on change SetContentStatic
    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Text", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata("", SetContentStatic));
    #endregion

    #region dependency property string HighlightText, on change SetContentStatic
    public string HighlightText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(HighlightTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(HighlightTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty HighlightTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HighlightText", typeof(string), typeof(HighlightTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata("", SetContentStatic));
    #endregion

    private static void SetContentStatic(
        DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = (HighlightTextBlock)d;
        control.SetContent();
    }

    #region dependency property Brush HighlightBrush, default = Orange
    public Brush HighlightBrush
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(ColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ColorProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "HighlightBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(HighlightTextBlock),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(Brushes.Orange));
    #endregion

    private TextBlock TextContent = new TextBlock();

    public HighlightTextBlock()
    {
        Content = TextContent;
        SetContent();
    }

    // текущий процесс обновления 
    Task currentWaitTask = null;
    private async void SetContent45() // это вариант для .NET 4.5
    {
        // для начала подождём 0.1 секунды
        var waitTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
        currentWaitTask = waitTask;
        await waitTask;
        // если за это время запустилось более новое обновление, выходим
        if (currentWaitTask != waitTask)
            return;
        currentWaitTask = null;

        // обновляем контент
        var parts = GetCombined(Text, HighlightText); 
        ApplyParts(parts);
    }

    private void SetContent() // это вариант для .NET 4.0
    {
        var mainTS = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        // для начала подождём 0.1 секунды
        var waitTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
        currentWaitTask = waitTask;
        waitTask.ContinueWith(t => // когда дождались:
            {
                // если за это время запустилось более новое обновление, выходим
                if (currentWaitTask != waitTask)
                    return;
                currentWaitTask = null;

                // обновляем контент
                var parts = GetCombined(Text, HighlightText);
                ApplyParts(parts);
            }, mainTS);
    }

    private void ApplyParts(List<string> parts)
    {
        var highlightBrush = HighlightBrush;
        System.Collections.IList existingInlines = TextContent.Inlines;
        var existingCount = existingInlines.Count;
        List<Inline> inlinesToAdd = null;
        var max = Math.Max(existingCount, parts.Count);
        for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
        {
            var text = i < parts.Count ? parts[i] : null;
            if (i < existingCount)
            {
                ((Run)existingInlines[i]).Text = text;
            }
            else // add new inline
            {
                var inline = new Run(text);
                if (i % 2 != 0) // highlight
                    inline.Background = highlightBrush;
                if (inlinesToAdd == null)
                    inlinesToAdd = new List<Inline>(parts.Count);
                inlinesToAdd.Add(inline);
            }
        }
        if (inlinesToAdd != null)
            TextContent.Inlines.AddRange(inlinesToAdd);
    }

    private List<string> GetCombined(string text, string highlightText)
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        if (text == null)
            return list;
        if (highlightText == null)
        {
            list.Add(text);
            return list;
        }

        var parts = text.Split(new[] { highlightText }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        bool first = true;
        foreach (var part in parts)
        {
            if (!first)
                list.Add(highlightText);
            list.Add(part);
            first = false;
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

---

Обновление: пришли в голову ещё два уточнения.

Во-первых, можно сравнить старый набор частей с новым, и если ничего не поменялось, не затевать дорогих многопоточных операций:

```
    List<string> oldParts = new List<string>();
    TaskScheduler mainTS;
    private void SetContent() // это вариант для .NET 4.0
    {
        var parts = GetCombined(Text, HighlightText);
        if (parts.SequenceEqual(oldParts))
            return;
        oldParts = parts;

        if (mainTS == null)
            mainTS = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        ...
```

Затем, можно отправлять изменения на более «спокойном» этапе жизни `Dispatcher`'а. При этом `Task` можно вовсе не приводить в главный контекст:

```
    List<string> oldParts = new List<string>();
    private void SetContent() // это вариант для .NET 4.0
    {
        var parts = GetCombined(Text, HighlightText);
        if (parts.SequenceEqual(oldParts))
            return;
        oldParts = parts;

        // подождём 0.1 секунды
        var waitTask = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.1));
        currentWaitTask = waitTask;
        waitTask.ContinueWith(t => // когда дождались:
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                // если за это время запустилось более новое обновление, выходим
                if (currentWaitTask != waitTask)
                    return;
                currentWaitTask = null;

                // обновляем контент
                ApplyParts(parts);
            }), DispatcherPriority.Input);
        });
    }
```

Этот вариант на моей машине ведёт себя лучше, особенно для случая, когда при изменении `HighlightText` ничего в реальности не меняется.

Comment: @AndreyK.: Придумал ещё вариант для ускорения. Пробуйте!