# Выделение строки в подстроке WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Допустим есть `datagrid`. В нем есть некоторое ключевое поле, по которому я делаю фильтрацию, считайте поиск. Механизм не важен. В момент фильтрации. Мне необходимо подсветить каждой строке грида, подстроку по которой идет поиск.

```
допустим ищем по подстроке три
**три**жды
с**три**жка
с**три**ж
```

Взял реализацию которая описана в данной статьи : [Выделение строки в подстроке](https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/32497/)

Данный метод идет в лоб. У нас грубо говоря будет 3 строки и 3 `textbox`. Это есть не очень хорошо. В моих условиях, в `datagrid` будет находиться порядка 80т-150т объектов.

Позже мной были найдены интересные вещи в xaml. В практически каждом контроле есть такая вещь как `<Run/>`. И сам по себе `textbox` можно описать через несколько `Run'ов`, и они будут линейно отображаться. Сама соль в том что `Run'у` можно повесить любой атрибут, например цвет фона. По идее можно описать конвертер, который берет строку которая находиться в `textbox` и подстроку поиска, задать ей фоновый цвет, и сформировать визуальное представление, данный способ мне кажется более гибким и красивым. Прошу помощи, может кто уже реализовывал похожие вещи!

Comment: Ну, `Run` есть внутри `TextBlock`'а. Да, можно его разбить на части, и любую часть перекрасить.

Comment: А вот и пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/639799/10105

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если кому интересно, вот реализация :

```
public class HighlightingTextBlock : TextBlock
{

    #region DependencyProperty

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SearchStringDependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SearchString", typeof (string), typeof (HighlightingTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
            {
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                PropertyChangedCallback = PropertyChangedCallback,
            });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextDependencyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof (string), typeof (HighlightingTextBlock),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(string.Empty)
            {
                DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
                PropertyChangedCallback = PropertyChangedCallback,
            });

    private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject _dependencyObject,
        DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs _dependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
        if (_dependencyObject is HighlightingTextBlock)
            ((HighlightingTextBlock) _dependencyObject).RedrawControl();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Properties

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(TextDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextDependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    public string SearchString
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(SearchStringDependencyProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SearchStringDependencyProperty, value); }
    }

    #endregion

    private void RedrawControl()
    {
       if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            if (!Text.Contains(SearchString))
            {
                ReturnEmpty();
                return;
            }
            string[] splitedBaseText = Regex.Split(Text, string.Format(@"({0})", SearchString),
                RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

            if (splitedBaseText.Any())
            {
                Inlines.Clear();
                foreach (var splited in splitedBaseText)
                {
                    if (splited == SearchString.ToLower())
                    {
                        Inlines.Add(new Run(splited) {Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Aqua)});
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Inlines.Add(new Run(splited));
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ReturnEmpty();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ReturnEmpty();
        }
    }

    private void ReturnEmpty()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Text))
        {
            Inlines.Clear();
            Inlines.Add(new Span(new Run(Text)));
        }
        else
        {
            Inlines.Clear();
            Inlines.Add(new Span(new Run(string.Empty)));
        }
    }
}
```